# How to send a warning message and update the page, after update the database

Tags: asp.net

I have this page where you can "edit" the data of the users... I want to send a message like "Edited Successfully" AND update the page as well, with the new content ( DropDownLists AND TextBoxes).

I'm using this for the messages:

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "alert", "alert('Edited Successfully !');", true);`

And to update the page, I tried:  `Response.Redirect(Request.RawURl)` and even a simple `Response.Redirect(~/page.aspx)` didnt work either...

If I try this way, it do update the page, but then it DOES NOT show the alert... ;\
All of this data (that fills the DropDownLists, Textboxes etc..) Is called on the Page_Load. I tried to call this same method after sending the message, but then it does not update =\

Any Idea?

Comment: you can use jquery alert messages http://akquinet.github.com/jquery-toastmessage-plugin/demo/demo.html

Comment: @SizS I know nothing about Javascript yet, guess jquery will be more complicated ;s what you think ?

Comment: what tool you're using for updating data e.g. FormView

Comment: Well, I have my textboxes/DropDownLists, I just get it's values using variables, then with MySql I insert into the database with the codebehind C#... WebPage

Comment: if you're not familiar with java script, simplest approach i can suggest: put panel(or a literal) on your aspx(initially visible=false), on your updating event set visible= true

Comment: @SizS ok, I've done that before, but why ? How I would update the fields AND show the message aswell ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25862/discussion-between-siz-s-and-ghaleon)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing occurs because you are reloading the page, so the script you register gets lost.

An approach I've used in cases like this, involves the use of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) Dialog:

In your page, put a div that will be the message container. It's hidden initially and will be shown after complete the database request:

```
<div id="modal" title="Alert" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

Write a javascript function that will display the dialog:

```
function showConfirmation(text){
    $("#modal").html(text).dialog({
          modal: true, // show the dialog as modal
          buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                  location.reload();
               }
           }, // add a button that refreshes the page when clicked
           closeOnEscape: false, // avoid the dialog close when ESC is pressed
           dialogClass: 'no-close' // adds a CSS class that hides the default close button
    });
}
```

The `dialog` function is responsible for showing the dialog, using the jQuery UI library. The `buttons` parameter displays a button that refreshes the page when pressed.

All you have to do is register the dialog script, with the `RegisterStartupScript` method:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "alert", "showConfirmation('Edited Successfully !');", true);
```

If you are not using jQuery and/or jQuery UI, all you have to do is add the references in head tag. If you don't want to use the [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)'s, download the files to your local site.

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

You can see a working example of the client side behavior [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AN74S/2/)

Comment: I'm starting to study Jquery. I just didnt understand one thing, what's the diference from your `RegisterStartupScript`  and mine ? Why exactly it will show something diferent ?

Comment: Because in your code you calling the browser default `alert`, which just show a message (there is no callback to its button). My code displays a customized dialog, build with HTML, which allow you to call any Javascript function on button click. In this, I've added code to refresh the page using Javascript, but you could cause a postback to the server with the same button and reload the page in `Page_Load`, using `Response.Redirect`. (Note the third parameter of `RegisterStartupScript`, in my example is calling `showConfirmation()` instead of `alert()`).

Comment: Got it ! Thaanks @MarcusVinicius ! I really appreciate your help. I'll test it right now, and as soon as I finish here, i'll come back and leave a feedback.